# error saying dim(x) must have positive length when trying to run friedman.test in R

Tags: r, statistics

I feel silly asking this question, but I am trying to do a simple friedman.test in R, and am getting an error. I want to compare various things, including just between two sample means, but for illustrative purposes, I'd like to compare the following four means.

```
ch03 <- 0.2251
Ic03 <- 0.2181
Pe03 <- 0.1768
Ta03 <- 0.2155

sample<-matrix(c(ch03,Ic03,Pe03,Ta03),ncol=4)

sample
      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
[1,] 0.2251 0.2181 0.1768 0.2155

#just doing the most basic thing to get the test working
friedman.test(sample)

#error
Error in apply(y, 1L, rank) : dim(X) must have a positive length
```

but I think what I am doing should work, based on the example here [enter link description here](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/polopoly_fs/1.714578!/file/stcp-marquier-FriedmanR.pdf)

Any thoughts would be much appreciated

Comment: The Friedman test doesn't make much sense if you only have one observation in each block. I'm not sure you are trying to use it the right way.

Comment: Hi There, I think I have figured it out. Does this make more sense (two observations, historic and contemporary, for each of four sites. make columns the historic contemp, and make rows the different sites. ch03 <- 0.2251
Ic03 <- 0.2181
Pe03 <- 0.1768
Ta03 <- 0.2155

ch15 <- 0.2278
Ic15 <- 0.2158
Pe15 <- 0.2092
Ta15 <- 0.2036

sample<-(c(ch03,Ic03,Pe03,Ta03))
sample2<-(c(ch15,Ic15,Pe15,Ta15))

mat <- cbind(sample, sample2)

friedman.test(mat)    
 Friedman rank sum test

data:  mat
Friedman chi-squared = 0, df = 1, p-value = 1

Comment: Yes, that's probably right, although I think the test is better for larger samples than this. In particular, the chi-squared approximation is not valid for small data, so that is perhaps why the results look odd.